# Script that finds the backup anywhere in the system with the time from today or yesterday

Tags: bash, backup

I'm creating this script that lookup anywhere in the system file for a backup with the selected regular expression parameters (http://regexr.com/3bve0) and check if the time is from today OR yesterday.

My current code is:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "The OS name is : $(uname -o)"

set a = $(tree -if / | grep -Po "(backup)?-?_?(?:\d*\d+)");
set cont=0;

for cont in {0..1000..1}
        do
        echo "Loop : $cont";
        if($a[$cont]!='')
                then
                if("$(date -r $a[$cont] +%Y%m&d)" == "$(date +%Y%m%d)" || "$(date -r $a[$cont] +%Y%m&d)" == "$(date +%Y%m%d-1)")
                then
                        echo " : The backup file is accepted as an validated backup file !";
                        echo "Path : $a[cont]";
                else("$(date -r $a[$cont] +%Y%m&d)" != "$(date +%Y%m%d)" || "$(date -r $a[$cont] +%Y%m&d)" != "$(date +%Y%m%d-1)")
                        echo " : This backup file is not validated with date from : YESTERDAY OR Today !!! \n";
                fi
        fi
        done
```

I'm getting this output:

```
Loop : 998
./det_linux_backups.sh: line 11: [998]!=: command not found
Loop : 999
./det_linux_backups.sh: line 11: [999]!=: command not found
Loop : 1000
./det_linux_backups.sh: line 11: [1000]!=: command not found
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @rojomoke Well the question currently is I'm getting a bad for loop, I don't really know the reason why.

Comment: Currently I'm getting a output which i Don't understand i'm printing the position right but not the value in the position

Comment: Try pasting your script into shellcheck.net.  You have several syntax errors

Comment: @rojomoke Than you very much I didn't know about the existance of such website!